# Laravel Eloquent join 2 tables together

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, userfrosting

I want to join 2 tables together using laravel eloquent. I could easily do this in mysql but have no idea using this.

I have a model called `device.php` this contains the following method:

```
public function wifi_client_connection(){
    return $this->hasMany('UserFrosting\WifiClientConnection');
}
```

but I need to link the `WifiClientConnection.php` model using a column called `mac_address` but `WifiClientConnection` doesnt have that column it has a column called `device_uuid`. The `mac_address` is converted into the `device_uuid` using the following method:

```
public function getDeviceUUID(){
    return hex2bin(md5($this->mac_address . $this->number));
}
```

In MySQL I join the 2 tables together like this:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN device ON wifi_client_connection.device_uuid = UNHEX(MD5(CONCAT(device.mac_address, device.number)))
```

how can I do something like that using Laravel Eloquent.

I also need the relationship the other way round so in the `WifiClientConnection.php` model I have this method:

```
public function device(){
    return $this->belongsTo('UserFrosting\WifiClientConnection');
}
```

but again I would need to convert the `device_uuid` to `mac_address` for this relationship to work

Thanks for any help

Comment: [Laravel QueryBuilder - Joins](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#joins)

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear - are you saying that you want to join the two tables on this transformed column?  I would suggest that you use a surrogate foreign key instead of trying to join in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a column with the converted value, then you can create the relationship.

```
public function device(){

    return $this->belongsTo('UserFrosting\WifiClientConnection', 'device_uuid', 'new_column_with_converted_value');
}
```

Comment: Is there a way of making the ```device.php``` think it has a column named ```device_uuid``` with the correct value when you call it?

Comment: Instead of actually adding the column to the ```device``` table

Comment: I don't want to say no, but i don't think so mate

Comment: alright thanks for the help I am trying to get around adding it to the db table thats all